# way to find out which message come from which server in rabbitmq?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

**1.Is there any way to find out message is coming from which server

2.can we restrict messages from some servers ?**

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Please expand it with more details.

Comment: Suppose,I have 1 rabbitmq server to which many server registered and many are producers but only specific are consumer .I want know which server exactly sent us a message. or any other way to block some producer from server(rabbitmq) itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an header while sending the messages:
`msg.getMessageProperties().getHeaders().put("server", "foobar")`

Then you can handle the messages differently in dependence of the header `server`.

Comment: That's implicit any other way on rabbitmq server itself ?

Comment: @AnkushNakaskar I don't know any other way